# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I got this exception when i try to get the list using NamedQuery:

`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query`

Below I mentioned code:

**Entity Class  Code:**

```
@Table(name = "tbl_users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "TblUsers.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TblUsers t")});
```

**DAO implement Code:**

```
org.hibernate.Query query = session.getNamedQuery("TblUsers.findAll");
List list = query.list();
```

Please provide solution for this exception.

Comment: Have you tried just "from TblUsers t"? This is the correct HQL syntax.

Comment: @Olaf - "select t from TblUsers t" is correct HQL as well

Comment: You need to show the whole stack trace. SQLGrammarException means SQL (as translated by Hibernate) was not accepted by your database. Make sure that the table exists (in proper schema).

Answer (score 11):

Was facing same issue for a while and figured out that the problem was due to the Table name being different from the class(or Entity) name in the database. Added the @Table(name = actual_table_name) annotation and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Get the SQL query that Hibernate is generating (using [hibernate.show_sql](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-properties) or, preferably, Hibernate's [SQL logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)), and execute it against the database yourself. That will most likely help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried using hibernate.show_sql but all I get is `insert into table (column) values (?)`  How can we actually see the REAL SQL and not just a bunch of `?` marks?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it could work.
It Perfectly worked for me.

1) Class level annotation.

```
@NamedQuery(name="UserDetails.byId" , query="from UserDetails where userId = ?")
```

2) Get record using NamedQuery

```
Query qry2 = sf.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("USER_DETAILS.byName")    ;
        qry2.setString(0, "Angad Bansode");
        List<UserDetails> user = qry2.list();
        for (UserDetails userDetails : user) {
            System.out.println("User Details by named native query  name = " + userDetails.getUserName() + ", aadhaar no  = " + userDetails.getAadharNo());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like this question is little old but any way once i added below line to hibernate config files it worked for me.

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was missing access to sequence for auto-increment primary key. After adding this error was resolved.

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL
    SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public
    TO "${user-name}";;
```